# Initilizing 2d char array with given values

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I'm having some trouble with initilizing this char array. It's supposed to be a 5x5 array initilized with the values given. When I run the program the compiler error states "Character constant too long for it's type". I haven't gotten to pointers yet, so I'm not supposed to use those yet. I will however be making methods to manipulate the 2d array, but I got stuck here

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char my_array [5][5];
    my_array = 'sweet','heart','egrit','clone','odor';   
    //cout<<"Hello World";

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: For starters, each individual array should be six characters, not five. You're forgetting the terminating `\0` byte. Then, in C++ strings use double-quotes not single-quotes. Finally, your C++ textbook should have plenty of examples of initializing arrays; is there something specific in your textbook's explanation or examples that you're unclear about?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - you only need `0`-terminator if you are going to process those sequences of characters like C-strings (including initializing that array with strings).

Comment: Chage char array to string array

Comment: I'm using the ninth edition of Starting out with C++. It does cover multi-dimensional arrays, but I didn't catch anyhthing on arrays of char data type. I do remember going over  the null terminating character in an udemy course I bought, so I'll go back and review that. School isn't currently in person so it's been a bit of a challenge to self learn. It's a lot easier to grasp concepts in a clasroom envirionment, but of course it can be done on your own.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is this:

```
char my_array [5][6] = { "sweet", "heart", "egrit", "clone", "odor" };
```

Note that the second dimension should be 6, not 5, to allow space for the terminating `nul` in each string.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to initialize 2D array, you can do it like this:

```
char my_array[5][5] = {
  {'s', 'w', 'e', 'e', 't'},
  {'h', 'e', 'a', 'r', 't'},
  {'e', 'g', 'r', 'i', 't'},
  {'c', 'l', 'o', 'n', 'e'},
  {'o', 'd', 'o', 'r', '?'},
};
```